# trigger jquery using button in dropdown

Tags: jquery, laravel, dropdown

I have a series of dropdown buttons on a page and am trying to trigger a single function with the button's id. Why is my function not getting called?

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-sm btn-block" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Options
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="lists/{{ $list['id'] }}/details">Edit Details</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Convert to...</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id= "{{ $list['id'] }}" class="copy-row">Copy</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
$('.copy-row').click( function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({url: '/lists/' + id, data: {_token:token}, type: 'PUT'})
  window.location.reload();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two separate class statements:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id= "{{ $list['id'] }}" class="copy-row">Copy</a>
```

changed to

```
<a class="dropdown-item copy-row" href="#" id= "{{ $list['id'] }}">Copy</a>
```